# Rails config.cache_store what happens this value evaluates to nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What happens if config.cache_store in configuration evaluates to nil in Rails?

I have been looking at my Rails application and trying to optimize it in production (Details - nearly 2 years old, API only, Rails 5.0.7, deployed on AWS EC2 with Ubuntu 16.04 OS, using nginx and puma). We have multiple production instances with an Application Load Balancer attached.

I was surprised to see this line in my production.rb:
`config.cache_store = :redis_store, ENV['REDIS_URL']`

We haven't set up any Redis servers for caching. And sure enough, `ENV['REDIS_URL']` was nil when I checked.

So, my question is - what happens in this situation? Is there no cache? Does it default to :file_store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use rails console in production to know which type of cache store is used

```
Rails.cache.class
```

I think in your case it will be `ActiveSupport::Cache::NullStore` and this means no real cache you can know more about this type of store here 
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/NullStore.html

Comment: I just checked and it is RedisStore - but without there actually being any redis url specified.

I guess it is safe to say that currently our api app simply doesn't have any caching in production at all! We should remedy that, shouldn't we?

Comment: I found that `RedisStore` behaves in a similar way to `NullStore` when Redis does not exist without raising errors. so now you don't have caching. you can set it to null store if you don't need caching to eliminate  confusion or configure it to use suitable cache store that really exits

Comment: I checked with the rails caching guide and you are right - it is behaving as NullStore currently. I am thinking of actually setting up a Redis server for caching. However, since ours is an API only app, we don't have assets to cache. SQL caching is already there. We could go for request or serializer caching, but I need to evaluate the pitfalls first. I don't want to be returning outdated data! Thanks for your comments.